# Integrating Android add network in my app

Tags: android, ads

I had created an app. Now my next task is to integrate **Ads network** in my app. But before that, I want to know:

1. What are the different **Ads network** that can be implemented in an android device?
2. Which **Ads network** is best suited for integrating in my app.
3. How to start with the integration.

So anyone please help me. If possible with examples and any documentation regarding this topic.

Regards
Anshuman

Comment: what is **add network**? can you point on the definition of it?

Comment: actually i mean to say that there are different add network like ADMOB,ADWHIRL..so i want to know how to add it to my app

Comment: So that is **Ads Network** not **Add Network**..

Comment: http://www.android-app-market.com/top-android-advertising-networks.html follow this link to know about add network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AdMob](http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android) is relatively easy and good to use. It came directly from google, so it is definately worth a choice and connects well with your google account.

**Add a new application/website to your Admob Account just enter "http://" as links. After that you can download the .zip file with included jar**

With [AdWhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/home/dev) you can integrate many different AdNetworks, this is a very nice feature also.

Comment: how that can be used..can you please send me some documentation or examples regarding that

Comment: click on those links the the developer-pages, free examples are coming with both api-downloads.

Comment: how can i download admob jar..do u have any link for that

Comment: you have to register on admob.com and then download the sample-client at: http://de.admob.com/api/download

Comment: ok i have downloaded the api..but they are all .php file from there how can i download admob jar file

Comment: i added a further note in my answer on top (it is in bold)

Comment: @AnimatedClocks let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2576/discussion-between-anshuman-and-animated-clocks)